# How to input of an set of points elegantly

Tags: c++, templates, generics, containers

I want to enter a set of points into a library, where each point of the set comprises of a set of co-ordinates.  I would like the input to be as flexible as possible to how the user of the library chooses to represent their data.

So I would like to be able to call the following pseudocode

```
template<int dimenension> //the dimension of each of the points
struct set_of_points
{
  void insert(Iterator first_point, Iterator last_point);
}
```

from any of the following,

```
struct set_of_points<2> s;
double points1[3][2] = {
  {1,2},
  {2,3},
  {4,5}
};
s.insert(points1, points1+3);

double p1[2] = {1,2}, p2[2] = {2,3}, p3[2] = {4,5};
double* points2[3] = {p1,p2,p3};
s.insert(points2, points2+3);

std::vector<double*> points3;
points3[0] = p1; points3[1] = p2; points3[2] = p3;
s.insert(points3.begin(), points3.end())
```

and I could add `vector<vector<double> >` and `vector< boost::array<double,2> >` to that list too.

The only way I can think to do this is to use extended, ugly and hand-crafted template magic.  For example, the pointer of arrays and pointer and pointers could be done like so.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_array.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_pointer.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/remove_pointer.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/and.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/or.hpp>

template<int dimenension> //the dimension of each of the points
struct set_of_points
{
  //  The coordinates of each point are represented as an array or a set of pointers,
  //   And each point is in an array.
  template<typename PointsItr>
  void
  insert(PointsItr P_begin, PointsItr P_end,
     typename boost::enable_if<  //enable if
       typename boost::mpl::and_<  
         boost::is_pointer< PointsItr >, //The set of points is a pointer, AND
         typename boost::mpl::or_< //either
         boost::is_array<typename boost::remove_pointer< PointsItr >::type >, //The points are an array
           boost::is_pointer<typename boost::remove_pointer< PointsItr >::type > //or are pointers
          >::type  //close or
         >::type //close and
       >::type* dummy = 0)
  {
    std::cout<<"inserted pointer of (pointers OR array)"<<std::endl;
  }

};

int
main  (int ac, char **av)
{
  struct set_of_points<2> s;
  double points1[3][2] = {
    {1,2},
    {2,3},
    {4,5}
  };
  s.insert(points1, points1+3);

  double p1[2] = {1,2}, p2[2] = {2,3}, p3[2] = {4,5};
  double* points2[3] = {p1,p2,p3};
  s.insert(points2, points2+3);

}
```

Yuk.  Is there a maintainable way of doing this?  If not, is there a way of tidying the template noise away into a library somehow so I don't have to write such code for every container I write.

Comment: sounds awfully complicated, why not define some restricted `point` types (`point2d`, `point3d` etc.) and then simply accept an iterator range of these points to insert into your set?

Comment: @Nim, I didn't expect it to be so complicated.  I wanted my library to 'just work' without the user having to repackage their data every time they use the library.  Yours is the simpler solution though - at least that way I can guarentee a `begin()` and `end()` method.

Comment: At the risk of sounding like an 80's surfer, that's some gnarly code dude.

Comment: Why don't you write another template class and pass your coordinates. And calculate length of array and write two functions begin() and end() in it.? Will be more scalable

Answer (score 0):

Okay, can't find an elegant way of doing this.

Here is the solution I got so far, it seems to cover most bases:

```
#include<iostream>

#include <boost/utility/enable_if.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_array.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_pointer.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/is_class.hpp>
#include <boost/type_traits/remove_pointer.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/and.hpp>
#include <boost/mpl/or.hpp>
#include <boost/array.hpp>

#include <vector>


template<int dimenension> //the dimension of each of the points
struct set_of_points
{
  //  The coordinates of each point are represented as an array or a set of pointers,
  //   And each point is in an array.
  template<typename PointsItr>
  void
  insert(PointsItr P_begin, PointsItr P_end,
     typename boost::enable_if<  //enable if
       typename boost::mpl::and_<  
         boost::is_pointer< PointsItr >, //The set of points is a pointer, AND
         typename boost::mpl::or_< //either
         boost::is_array<typename boost::remove_pointer< PointsItr >::type >, //The points are an array
           boost::is_pointer<typename boost::remove_pointer< PointsItr >::type > //or are pointers
              >::type  //close or
         >::type //close and
       >::type* dummy = 0)
  {
    //get the type of the array
    std::cout<<"inserted pointer of (pointers OR array)"<<std::endl;
  }

  //  The coordinates of each point are represented as an array or a set of pointers,
  //   And each point is in a container.
  template<typename PointsItr>
  void
  insert(PointsItr P_begin, PointsItr P_end,
     typename boost::enable_if<  //enable if
       typename boost::mpl::and_<  
         boost::is_pointer< PointsItr >, //The set of points is a pointer, AND
         boost::is_class<typename boost::remove_pointer< PointsItr >::type> //The points are wrapped in a class, assume has a begin and end method
         >::type //close and
       >::type* dummy = 0)
  {
    //get the type of the array
    std::cout<<"inserted pointer of container"<<std::endl;
  }

  //  The coordinates of each point are represented as a class,
  //   And each point is an array or pointer
  template<typename PointsItr>
  void
  insert(PointsItr P_begin, PointsItr P_end,
     typename boost::enable_if<  //enable if
       typename boost::mpl::and_<  
         boost::is_class< PointsItr >, //The set of points is a class, AND
         typename boost::mpl::or_< //either
           boost::is_array<typename PointsItr::value_type >, //The points are an array
           boost::is_pointer<typename PointsItr::value_type> //or are pointers
           >::type  //close or
         >::type //close and
       >::type* dummy = 0)
  {
    //get the type of the array
    std::cout<<"inserted container of pointers"<<std::endl;
  }

  //  The coordinates of each point are represented as a class,
  //   And each point is a class
  template<typename PointsItr>
  void
  insert(PointsItr P_begin, PointsItr P_end,
     typename boost::enable_if<  //enable if
       typename boost::mpl::and_<  
         boost::is_class< PointsItr >, //The set of points is a class, AND
           boost::is_class<typename PointsItr::value_type > //The points are a class
         >::type //close and
       >::type* dummy = 0)
  {
    //get the type of the array
    std::cout<<"inserted container of containers"<<std::endl;
  }
};

int
main  (int ac, char **av)
{
  struct set_of_points<2> s;
  double points1[3][2] = {
    {1,2},
    {2,3},
    {4,5}
  };
  s.insert(points1, points1+3);

  double p1[2] = {1,2}, p2[2] = {2,3}, p3[2] = {4,5};
  double* points2[3] = {p1,p2,p3};
  s.insert(points2, points2+3);

  boost::array<double,2> p4,p5,p6;
  p4[0] = 1.0; p4[1] = 2.0;
  p5[0] = 1.0; p5[1] = 2.0;
  p6[0] = 1.0; p6[1] = 2.0;
  boost::array<double,2> points3[3] = {p4,p5,p6};
  s.insert(points3, points3+3);

  std::vector<double*> points4(3);
  points4[0]=p1; points4[1]=p2; points4[2]=p3;
  s.insert(points4.begin(), points4.end());

  std::vector<boost::array<double,2> > points5(3);
  points5[0]=p4; points5[1]=p5; points5[2]=p6;

  s.insert(points5.begin(), points5.end());


}
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no standard way to do what you ask because if a double* represents a point (as in points2, points3) you don't know how big the array is. Unless of course you trust the user of your library to give the correct size and not cause a segfault (don't do that :-) ).

However, if you want to allow a vector, c-style double array, or any container of doubles represent a point, consider using `BOOST_FOREACH` (or C++11 foreach loops):

```
template <typename T>
Point MakePoint(const T& pointData)
{
    Point p;
    BOOST_FOREACH(double& x, pointData)
    {
        // check p isn't full
        p.Add(x);
    }

    return p;
}
```

(Don't worry about the fancy enable_if stuff, BOOST_FOREACH or c++11 foreach will ensure that T is a container of doubles.)